# Importing node modules to web worker in React/Webpack app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, import, web-worker

I have a React app bundled with Webpack.  I would like to use a web worker for one of my components, which exports data to Pdf.  The generation of the pdf can take a while and lock the browser, so I want to do this work in a web worker to do it in a separate thread.  The problem I am having is importing the JsPDF library into my web worker script so i can use it.

This is my worker script:

```
import * as JsPDF from "jspdf";

export default () => {
    self.addEventListener("message", event => {
        const canvases = event.data;

        const pdf = new JsPDF({
            orientation: "l",
            unit: "in",
        });
        // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-for-of
        for (let i = 0; i < canvases.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) pdf.addPage();
            pdf.addImage(canvases[i].toDataURL("image/png"), "PNG", 0.25, 0, 11, 8);
        }
        pdf.save("report.pdf");
        self.postMessage("done", "");
    });
};
```

This gives me this error at runtime:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jspdf__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is not defined
    at blob:http://localhost:11449/ea75c456-15ee-45e9-b82b-902c518dc635:4
```

I did also try using the importScript() function, like so:

```
export default () => {
    importScripts("jspdf");
    self.addEventListener("message", event => {
        const canvases = event.data;

        const pdf = new JsPDF({
            orientation: "l",
            unit: "in",
        });
        // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-for-of
        for (let i = 0; i < canvases.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) pdf.addPage();
            pdf.addImage(canvases[i].toDataURL("image/png"), "PNG", 0.25, 0, 11, 8);
        }
        pdf.save("report.pdf");
        self.postMessage("done", "");
    });
};
```

and I get this error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The URL 'jspdf' is invalid.
```

or I try:

```
importScripts("../../../../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js");
```

and I get the same invalid URL error.
I also tried using require outside of the export:

```
const JsPDF = require("jspdf");
```

but i still get an error that JsPDF is not defined. What else can I try?

I should mention that the web worker is instantiated using a custom class, as in https://medium.com/prolanceer/optimizing-react-app-performance-using-web-workers-79266afd4a7, for getting the correct URL with webpack:

```
export default class WebWorker {
    constructor(worker: any) {
        const code = worker.toString();
        const blob = new Blob([`(${code})()`]);
        return new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    }
}
```

Comment: Webpack should definitely support importing installed npm packages. Is `target: "webworker"` set in your webpack config for the worker bundle?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ended up using [worker-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader) for webpack.  This allows me to import modules in worker scripts like in any other script.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald the link above is broken. It seems to be omitted a character 'h'

Comment: had you already ejected the app? Were there any issues with the ts compiler hanging like described here https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8707#issuecomment-606475886 –

Comment:  This answer is only for the old **Webpack 4**, as this is has been *deprecated* in version **5+** because it's already built in. Also, this is not an answer at all, but merely a link, and should have been posted as a comment, as the question is still standing unanswered,